# Envoy/GRPC cannot decode binary data - bad wiretype

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, envoyproxy

I have a proxy (envoy) which routes requests to a backend (Hoverfly on HTTP1.1). Envoy takes a gRPC request, translates it to HTTP1.1 and sends it to Hoverfly. Hoverfly responds with as expected and Envoy is converts that to gRPC and returns the entire response.

Hoverfly responds with a HEX encoding of bytes and Envoy tries to decode that. In that process I see an like this:

```
ERROR:
  Code: Internal
  Message: grpc: failed to unmarshal the received message proto: bad wiretype
```

I've been reading online that a `bad wiretype` could mean something like data being corrupted, or the string to byte conversion is messed up, etc. I'm unsure what's happening here - can someone help?

Edit:
I used the `protoc --encode` and `hexdump` commands to get the hexdump which looks like this:

```
00000000  0a 06 66 6f 6f 62 61 72                           |..foobar|
00000008
```

^ This is exactly what Hoverfly returns in the response body (when I ping it directly and not thru the proxy)

```
curl -i -XPOST "localhost:8811/kv.KV/Get" -d '{"key":"foo", "value":"bar"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 79
content-type: application/json
hoverfly: Was-Here
date: Wed, 14 Jul 2021 00:30:48 GMT
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 9
server: envoy

00000000  0a 06 66 6f 6f 62 61 72                           |..foobar|
00000008
```

When Envoy tries to "unmarshall" that response, it throws the `bad wiretype` error

My proto file looks like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package kv;

message GetRequest {
  string key = 1;
}

message GetResponse {
  string value = 1;
}

service KV {
  rpc Get(GetRequest) returns (GetResponse);
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: An invalid wire type indeed means that the payload is corrupt somehow. You could try running the hex through https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode, and see what it says? If you have trailing zeros, that also indicates a problem, although I'd expect that to complain about an invalid tag or field (since a 00 header has wire-type zero, which is a valid wire-type, even though the field number - also zero here - is not valid)

Comment: I ran it thru that website, it did not give me any output - is it broken?

Comment: @Saturian there's a UI bug I need to fix - check the console output (it runs client-side); it is *probably* complaining about an invalid wire type? (I'll be at my desk in a bit - will check then)

Comment: when I run it through the site, I get `Field #1: 0A String Length = 6, Hex = 06, UTF8 = "foobar"` - which... seems valid? so presumably the bytes being received by the final step aren't those same bytes?

Comment: Yeah, except I don't know what else to do :-( I set the application type to `application/x-protobuf` but Envoy (or the grpc module) still does not process it correctly :-(